# Yeast not slowing under refrigeration

Tags: bottling, carbonation, soda

I'm using Red Star champagne yeast to brew natural sodas, but I'm stuck on one issue:

After the room-temp fermentation I move the (2-liter soda) bottles to the refrigerator (38°F) but the fermentation continues at about the same pace.  The bottles show significant bulging after just 8-10 hours.

Should I switch yeasts or is there something else I can do to slow the fermentation so that I can safely move the product into glass bottles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about champagne yeast (and other wine yeasts) is that they have been selected to eat a lot a of fermentable sugar with little nutrients around. Another facet of this is, even though the yeast is recommended for a particular temperature doesn't mean it won't ferment outside that range, or wake up later to finish the job.

As long as there is live yeast and a bunch of sugar around, you can't really "safely move the product into glass bottles". There's a reason champagne bottles are so heavy, and the cork is held in with wire!

People that make hard cider have [similar problems](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/sweet-sparkling-cider-without-pasteurizing-sulphites-or-lactose), maybe their methods would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the yeast isn't going to sleep fast enough. You could try putting the bottles into the freezer for a short time before refrigerating in order to reduce the temperature rapidly.

Comment: It is still happening after a few days in the fridge, though.  Is this strain of yeast really cold-tolerant?

Comment: Thats a good point.. from what I can see online is the low range of that yeast is 59F which is still a decent difference to 38F. Have you tried putting some in the freezer?

Comment: Not yet, but I'll try that.